# Undefined identifiers

Tags: c++, undefined, header-files, codewarrior

I am trying to recompile source code of an old game, which was not coded by me and I've no idea which compiler was used to compile this.

I am getting undefined identifier errors in a file which I couldn't figure out.  The errors are like this:

```
Error : Undefined identifier 'begin'  
Error : Undefined identifier 'capacity'  
Error : Undefined identifier 'size'  
Error : Undefined identifier 'back'  
Error : Undefined identifier 'pop_back'
```

I am pretty sure I am missing one or two header files. Any idea which headers I am missing there?

Here are the code lines which are giving errors:

```cpp
const OzU32 nCapacity = OzU32(capacity());
const OzU32 nAllocated = Capacity() - OzU32(size());
std::transform(
            m_pPoolMemory, 
            m_pPoolMemory + nCapacity, 
            begin(), 
            std::ptr_fun(SetPointer<Type>));
```

PS: I am using CodeWarrior IDE, if that helps.

Comment: Which compiler are you using now?

Comment: seems like std::vector methods

Comment: Should I give you the code lines, since including <vector> is not working

Comment: @Bathsheba I have no idea about compiler, but it was some old visual studio version, may be 2003/2005.

Comment: And which compiler are you using now?

Comment: I am using Freescale CodeWarriror now

Comment: @devnull It's old, so I don't think it's boost.

Comment: @spiritwolfform you were right, it's the std::vector

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually there were some other header files, which have the same method names, causing the compiler confusion. So I just added the vector namespace in front of the method name to work it out. Like this -

```
vector<Type>::begin()
```

And yeah it was vector.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your compiler is either missing some of the standard library or hasn't been installed/configured properly.

You can either:

1. Fix the compiler's configuration (particularly check the include paths)
2. Switch to a different compiler
3. Install a third party version of the missing library (look at [stlport](http://www.stlport.org/))
4. Replace the code in the program you are working on which use the missing library classes

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty simple most likely you forgot to put std:: before these keywords. or you could simply write this at the top of your code: using namespace std;

By doing this you don't need to pressed them with std:: but i would not recommend doing it as it may cause problems in long codes

Comment: damn im more than 10 years late 